# How to fix "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma' " issue in google cloud console

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pyenv, lzma

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "reader.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (  # noqa: F401
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 88, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 71, in <module>
    from pandas.io.formats.format import DataFrameFormatter, format_percentiles
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import _expand_user, _stringify_path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 9, in <module>
    import lzma
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
from _lzma import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "server.py", line 9, in <module>
    from search import Search
  File "/home/n_pawar0414/20deg-c/search.py", line 6, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import (
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper, NamedAgg
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from pandas.core.groupby.generic import (  # noqa: F401
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py", line 44, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py", line 88, in <module>
    from pandas.core.generic import NDFrame, _shared_docs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 71, in <module>
    from pandas.io.formats.format import DataFrameFormatter, format_percentiles
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/format.py", line 47, in <module>
    from pandas.io.common import _expand_user, _stringify_path
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/common.py", line 9, in <module>
import lzma
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/lzma.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _lzma import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_lzma'
```

I have attempted to install **pyenv** as well as uninstall python and reinstall it with no luck

The code works on my laptop just fine and runs with no error, i only have the error when running my code on google cloud shell.

The requirements I have installed are:

```
pandas==0.25.0
nose==1.3.7
tornado==6.0.3
numpy==1.17.0
nltk==3.4.4
pyspellchecker==0.5.0
tqdm==4.32.2
ujson==1.35
cachetools==3.1.1
flask==1.1.1
flask_cors==3.0.8
gevent==1.4.0
openpyxl==2.6.2
xlrd==1.2.0
```

The issue is that there is no module named **_lzma** present in/on google cloud console

Comment: Similar problem: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/27532

Comment: i attempted this, it didn't work for me

Comment: We need more details, when you say "when deploying my code on google cloud", where are you deploying it? What is the configuration you're using for that deployment?

Comment: i edited my question, the command that I give to run it is ``` python3 myFileName.py ```

Comment: Can you please share a minimal reproducible example of your code (both main and requirements) for us? that will help us to make a proper and quick debugging of this for you ;-)

Comment: I added the requirements, i hope this helps debug my problem a little.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using cloud shell, this is an expected behaviour since cloud shell vms are ephemeral  and are not prepared to work like full development environment, for this reason the python installation is incomplete, you can use a [compute engine always free instance](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#always-free-usage-limits) to have an small and not preemptible instance  to try your code.